# Modified All view in Jenkins, can't see Folders

Tags: jenkins, directory

Some time ago I replaced the All view in my Jenkins installation with a Nested View that has tabs and sub-tabs on it.

I've upgraded to Jenkins v2, and would like to try out the Folders plugin. I created a new test folder, but now I can't find it. Where do they go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had replaced my ALL view according to these instructions: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Editing+or+Replacing+the+All+View

I still had an "ALL" tab of view type "ALL". The folders are in there.